# Error connecting to Github from Heroku Dashboard

Tags: github

I'm building a pipeline and have created a new app under Heroku dashboard.

Under the "Deploy" tab, I have selected Deployment method has "Github".

It reveals a "Connect to Github" button.

This button presents an authorization window to grant Heroku permissions to access my Github account. When I grant the permission, the window is dismissed but then I see an error notification in red color in the upper right corner with following message.

**Couldn't connect to GitHub
Error: remote was closed, authorization was denied, or an authentication message otherwise not received before the window closed.**

I checked under Github.com account, and I see that Heroku dashboard is already granted access  ( "Full control of private repositories") to my account.

Is there a reason for getting this error? How can I clear it?

Answer (score 1):

This was most likely a problem with Cookies. I used the incognito mode of the browser and the error disappeared.